# Can't load CSS background image URL

Tags: html, css, angular5

Error in my Angular 5 project.
Styles.css

```
body {
background-image: url("D:/angular4pj/my-ap/src/aaa.jpeg");
}
```

Error:
ERROR in ./src/aaa.jpeg
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Comment: did you google that error ? we cannot help you if you **only** give the error

Comment: You need to use a relative path - relative to the css file.  Or a website address of the image - not the filepath on the computer

Comment: i already search, but i cant find any solution

Comment: It works with a website address, but I want to use the path from my computer. Any solution?

Comment: try `aaa.jpeg`.

Answer (score -1):

Add the image to your angular assets folder. Something like:

- **yourproject > src > assets > > images > aaa.jpeg.**

Then in your CSS:

```
body{
  background-image:url("/assets/images/aaa.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. 
Console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Interesting. I just tested this and it works. Did you copy the code above exactly? One thing I noticed is that in my example i used "jpg" and you have "jpeg". Could that be the issue?

Comment: yes i used "jpg".

 HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - http://localhost:4200/assets/images/aaa.jpg

Comment: Just to confirm: In your question your image has a "jpeg" extension. In your comment above you're using a "jpg" extension (my bad in my answer). Are you using the right extension?

Comment: My image has a "jpeg" extension. I copy your code but it doesn't work. Then I change aaa.jpg to aaa.jpeg, it still doesn't work. What should I do?